# empty log rocket console messages?

Tags: javascript, logging, logrocket

I'm seeing a lot of empty console entries in LogRocket:

[image]

LogRocket is definitely capable of logging JS errors as this script demonstrates:

```
<script src="https://cdn.lr-ingest.io/LogRocket.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
if (window.LogRocket) {
    window.LogRocket.init('vqaibs/test-pkcaa');
}
</script>
<script>
zzz();
console.log('hello, world!');
</script>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

That produces out that looks like this:

[image]

So what I'm wondering is if LogRocket is only capable of logging *certain* types of errors. Like maybe the blank entries are errors that LogRocket doesn't log? If so then how might I capture these errors?